# Django 1.6 urls not working

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and trying to figure out how the urls work in Django.

My app's **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))
```

Project **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
)
```

`APPEND_SLASH = True` is set in `settings.py` and **app** is included in **INSTALLED_APPS**.

I get the **Page Not Found** when i go to `localhost:8000/app`.

Now i am not able to go to `localhost:8000/admin` also.

```
RuntimeError at /admin/
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

app's **views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is Hello")
```

Settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

APPEND_SLASH = True
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'bfa&y-8d4^c&6a4hqz^am^1-xce05oj6&_$n!t=$v10fka(-!w'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'app',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'appmain.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appmain.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

What i am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong. Is your app in settings INSTALLED_APPS? And can you post the views.index?

Comment: Did you set `APPEND_SLASH` to `False`? If this is the case, you need to go to `localhost:8000/app/`

Comment: Did you have the CommonMiddleware installed? Or changed `APPEND_SLASH`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: I have set `APPEND_SLASH = True` but still its not working and my app is also listed in installed apps.

Comment: Do you have the DEBUG flag set to True in your settings ? If no, set it and you'll get a message about which patterns where looked for. Also, what happens when you try the /admin/ url ?

Comment: What's the code the function `index` in views.py plz?

Comment: Please post both tracebacks.

Comment: Already its there in the question.

Comment: try `localhost:8000/admin/` . is it ok ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your urls.

In settings:

```
DEBUG = True
```

Reload `http://localhost:8000/app/` and post the traceback to Stackoverflow.

**UPDATE**

I build a Django project and used the code you supplied. It runs fine. Are you sure `http://localhost:8000/app/` gives a 404? `http://localhost:8000/` does 404, which is expected because there is no view for `/`.

The admin works also. To investigate the 'maximum recursion' you should supply models.py and admin.py code.

Some advice: Rename your project. `appmain` (for the project) and `app` (for the app) are confusing since they look alike, but more important `appmain` isn't an app but a project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The view is okay. Do you use the build in development server?

Comment: Yes the default one which comes with Django.

Comment: @user3012137: Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Worth trying:

Change your project urls.py to something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app/', include('project.app.urls')),
)
```