# Django 1.6 - Sending Parameters in url, raising the url miss match error?

Tags: python, django, url

I have a list of items in an html file as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block Content %}
   <div id="movie_list">
      {% for movie in movies %}
         <p class="movie-title"><a href="/movie/{{ movie.slug }}/">{{ movie.name }}</a> </p>
      {% endfor %}
</div> {% endblock %}
```

It displays a list of movies name which every item in this list is a link! I try to send a request to  server to see a specific movie according to the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

The model handles this request is as follows:

```
def SpecificMovie(request, movie_slug):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(slug=movie_slug)
    context = {'movies': movie}
    return render_to_response('single_movie.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It responds to the request according the `movie_slug` passed into it!

the `single_movie.html` file is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block Content %}
  <div id="single_moive">
    <p class="movie-title">Name: {{ movies.name }}</p>

    <p class="movie-title">Des: {{ movies.description }}</p>

    <p class="movie-title">Country: {{ movies.country }}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and my `urlpatterns` var is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
                   (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
                   (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   (r'^movie/$', 'movie_page.views.MoviesAll'),
                   (r'^movie/(?P<movie_slug>.)/$', 'movie_page.views.SpecificMovie'),
)
```

But when I click on each item in receive an error saying that there is miss match in the url pattern. An snapshot of the page is as follows:
[image: error 404]

as you can see everything seems ok! but I don't know what the problem is! I read the following links([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729762/django-1-6-urls-not-working),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556270/django-tutorial-3-indexpage-missing), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000986/django-registration-1-0-with-django-1-6-and-python-3-3-4)) but Thanks for any comments.

Comment: A dot (.) matches just one character.

Comment: It does not solve the problem. I removed the dot but the problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex `(?P<movie_slug>.)` matches a single character. You probably want `(?P<movie_slug>.+)`.

Comment: +1 though `.+` is too greedy. A specific regex for slug could be better here `(?P<movie_slug>[\w-]+)`

Comment: I removed the dot before but the problem didn't solve! Why this happened?

Comment: @Constantine You want to match one or more characters. The dot matches one, and adding the `+` makes it match one or more. Removing the dot makes it match nothing.